# Determine at runtime which db provider is being used, with EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In our ASP.NET Core and EF Core system, we use different databases for different parts of the system. I need to be able to tell, at runtime, which db provider is being used, because some stuff needs to take this into account.

During startup, there is this for SQL Server:

```
  services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(
    options => options.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
  );
```

or this for SQLite:

```
  services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(
    options => options.UseSqlite(config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
  );
```

*The point being that the knowledge of which database is being used, is contained within the system, somewhere.*

At some arbitrary point in the system, how can I determine which database I'm using? I have access to the `MyContext`. Is there something in there that can reveal this info?

Comment: define "dynamic" here. Dynamic as "per application startup" or dynamic like "can change any time at runtime"?

Comment: @Tseng As in to determine programmatically at runtime.

Comment: Both is runtime, that's why I ask.If its a "per application startup" thing, you can just add the type of the provider in addition to the connection string to the appsettings.json.

Comment: @Tseng that's an interesting alternative... I can place any random stuff into the connection string? What format should I use?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Anywhere in the system, where you have access to the `MyContext`, do this:

```
context.Database.GetDbConnection().GetType().Name
```

For example, it is `SqliteConnection` for SQLite, or `SqlServerConnection` for SQL Server, etc.

**However I'm not sure if you'll need to dispose the connection afterwards!**

Answer (score 22):

I use in my project 3 database providers.

- **Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL**
- **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer**
- **Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql**

Not used in my project. **Update**. June 17, 2020. I noticed that the Oracle Provider has an extensión method IsOracle.

- **Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore** [Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore 3.19.0-beta1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore/3.19.0-beta1)

Include in your client project, any of those references, can be added from Nuget Package manager or CLI.

The references contains the following extension methods.

```
Boolean isPostgreSQL = context.Database.IsNpgsql();
Boolean isSqlServer = context.Database.IsSqlServer();
Boolean isMySql = context.Database.IsMySql();
Boolean isOracle= context.Database.IsOracle();
```

---

**Example 1**

```
public static EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> ToTable<TEntity>(this EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder, string schema, DatabaseFacade database) where  TEntity : class
{
    switch(database)
    {
        case DatabaseFacade db when db.IsMySql():
            builder.ToTable($"{schema}.{typeof(TEntity).Name}");
            break;

        case DatabaseFacade db when db.IsSqlServer() | db.IsNpgsql():
            builder.ToTable(typeof(TEntity).Name, schema);
            break;
        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException("Unknown database provider.");
    }
    return builder;
}
```

**Example 2**

```
private static string GetEffectiveConstraintName(string name, DatabaseFacade database)
{
    return database switch
    {
        DatabaseFacade db when db.IsSqlServer() => name,
        DatabaseFacade db when db.IsNpgsql() => name.Length < DataAccessConstants.PostgreSqlIdentifierMaxLength ? name : name.Substring(0, DataAccessConstants.PostgreSqlIdentifierMaxLength),
        DatabaseFacade db when db.IsMySql() => name.Length < DataAccessConstants.MySqlIdentifierMaxLength ? name : name.Substring(0, DataAccessConstants.MySqlIdentifierMaxLength),
        _ => throw new NotImplementedException("Unknown database provider")
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For EF Core 2:

```
dbContext.Database.ProviderName
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there is a public way of doing it, but you can look at context.Database.DatabaseCreator (you'll have to use reflection to get to DatabaseCreator), but by looking at the type, you can tell what kind of connection it is. For example, with SQL, you'll get SqlServerDatabaseCreator.

EDIT: Yeah, looking at the code, I don't think there is any other way to tell besides what I mentioned above. The UseSqlServer method doesn't set any flags anywhere or anything like that. It's just a factory.

Answer (score 1):

One point where you could start is the `DbContextOptions<T>`, which is what the `AddDbContext<T>` method does, which you can see [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/1145ef9b3dd46a07a84cb04b11141ecc8bfc62d2/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L153-L156).

Which in turn gets injected into the DbContext.

You could try to request `DbContextOptions` or `DbContextOptions<MyContext>` in your service too and then interate/inspect the [Extensions](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/DbContextOptions.cs#L37) dictionary.

`SqliteOptionsExtension` is Sqlite one, you can see it registered [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite/SqliteDbContextOptionsBuilderExtensions.cs#L110) and [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite/SqliteDbContextOptionsBuilderExtensions.cs#L33-L35).